# Cannot login to Stack Overflow on another computer

Tags: support, login

I am logged in to Stack Overflow on this computer. When I click my name at the top, I can see my profile and my email address. But if I try that email address on another computer to login to Stack Overflow, through Stack Exchange, it says

> No account with this email found.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't look like you have a Stack Exchange OpenID. The contact email address on your profile isn't necessarily the same as an email you can use to log in.

If you look at your profile on the machine where you're still signed in, you can click "my logins" to view the credentials you have registered with us and add other ones if needed.

Comment: It worked!  I then went to new computer, did Stackoverflow login, selected "click here to recover your account" and used the email addr from "my logins".